# Javascript setting date format including 0 with date and month

Tags: javascript

Essentially I am trying to convert a date such as 2019-02-09 to 09-02-2019. I have the following:

```
var newDate = new Date('2019-02-09');
strDate = newDate.getDate() + "-" + (newDate.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + newDate.getFullYear();
```

which works but will output 9-2-2019. Is there a neat method (ie not checking getDate and getMonth less than 10) to get the output 09-02-2019?

Comment: No not out of the box with the standard date object. You either need to make your own function to get it in that format. Or I highly rate the momentjs library, which supports what you need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `padStart` to achieve your goal.

```js
var newDate = new Date('2019-02-09');
strDate = newDate.getDate().toString().padStart(2, "0") + "-" + (newDate.getMonth() + 1).toString().padStart(2, "0") + "-" + newDate.getFullYear();

console.log(strDate);
```

Answer (score 3):

Using [toLocaleDateString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString):

```js
var dt = new Date('2019-02-09');

var x = dt.toLocaleDateString('en-US', { year: 'numeric', month: '2-digit', day: '2-digit' })
          .replace(/[^0-9]/g, '-');



console.log(x);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use the [toLocaleDateString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString) method and choose `en-GB` as the locale to return your date in the **DD/MM/YYYY** format and use a simple `split()` and `join()` or regex to replace `/` with `-` like this:

---

**Split and Join approach:**

```js
var newDate = new Date('2019-02-09');    
strDate = newDate.toLocaleDateString('en-GB').split("/").join("-");    
alert(strDate);
```

---

**Regex:**

```js
var newDate = new Date('2019-02-09');    
strDate = newDate.toLocaleDateString('en-GB').replace(/[^0-9]/g, '-');    
alert(strDate);
```